# Pubnub PHP subscribe/publish

Tags: php, mysql, curl, publish-subscribe, pubnub

I have successfully uploaded sensor data from CC3200 to pubnub.
Now I want to subscribe to that channel's data using PHP and store it in my local database.

Where can I get the code for subscribing and publishing to the datastream using PHP?

I tried some codes but got errors like `undefined CURLOPT_USERAGENT in client.php`? I have attached my code in image format.

These are the following errors I got :

1)Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_USERAGENT - assumed 'CURLOPT_USERAGENT' in C:\webserver\www\Client.php on line 76
2)Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER - assumed 'CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER' in C:\webserver\www\Client.php on line 77
3)Call to undefined function Pubnub\Clients\curl_init() in C:\webserver\www\Client.php on line 114

Do I have to add curl header files in the code?![PHP code][1]

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2A7K.jpg
```

Comment: I'm assuming you don't have curl installed? since the docs clearly indicate  the constants you are using exist. http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Comment: I have curl installed (windows version). Does CURL and the PHP have to be inside same folder / directory ?

Comment: Post the output of a phpinfo() call: http://v1.jontangerine.com/silo/php/phpinfo/

Comment: The error provided din your question and the code provided as per screenshot do not make sense.

Comment: I tried to attach the code in image format but the image can only be uploaded by stackflow user with 10 credits. So i think image did not upload .

Comment: I'm unable to subscribe to my channel in dev console of pubnub. Anyone has any idea..

Comment: Also if anyone has working subscribe code pls help .                        pubnub->subscribe('1', function ($envelope) {print_r($envelope['message']); return true;});                                                                       This code returns syntax error

Comment: Did you follow the docs: http://www.pubnub.com/docs/php/pubnub-php-sdk#subscribe 

Let us know if you still need assistance by contacting support@pubnub.com and we'll post answer back here.